# creating same values within a group using retain statement in SAS

Tags: sas, retain

I am trying to create a variable z that will take the same value within a group based on values of two variables X and Y of the first observation within a group. There are 4 possible values of Z a group can take based on the X and Y values of the first observation in the group.

```
Z=1 (if X=1 & Y=1), 
Z=2 (if X=2 & Y=1),
Z=3 (if X=1 & Y=2), and 
Z=4 (if X=2 & Y=2).
```

This is what I have and what I want.

```
X has two values, 1 or 2, within a group; while Y can take 1, 2 ,3. 
Y is sorted in ascending order 
if the first (or all group observations) take a value of 3, the resulting Z 
value should be set to missing
```

This is what I have:

```
Obs    Group          X            Y
1      10600          1            1
2      10600          1            2
3      10600          1            3
4      10800          2            1
5      10800          2            3
6      10900          1            2
7      10900          1            3
8      11100          2            2
9      11100          2            2
10     11100          2            3
11     11100          2            2
12     11200          2            3
13     11300          2            1
14     11300          2            2
15     11300          1            3
16     11300          1            3
17     11300          1            3
18     11300          1            3
```

And here is what I want:

```
Obs    Group          X            Y         Z
1      10600          1            1         1
2      10600          1            2         1
3      10600          1            3         1
4      10800          2            1         2
5      10800          2            3         2
6      10900          1            2         3
7      10900          1            3         3
8      11100          2            2         4
9      11100          2            2         4
10     11100          2            3         4
11     11100          2            2         4
12     11200          2            3         .
13     11300          2            1         2
14     11300          2            2         2
15     11300          1            3         .
16     11300          1            3         .
17     11300          1            3         .
18     11300          1            3         .
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that a `retain`ed variable will carry a value into forward iterations of the data step.  Nominally, a simple data step with a single `set` statement an iteration will correspond to a row in the data set.

Your retained variable is to be assigned at the start of a group, so you will need a `by` statement, which in turn makes an automatic flag variable `first.<by-group-var>` available.

```
data have; input
Group  X Y; datalines;
10600  1 1
10600  1 2
10600  1 3
10800  2 1
10800  2 3
10900  1 2
10900  1 3
11100  2 2
11100  2 2
11100  2 3
11100  2 2
11200  2 3
11300  2 1
11300  2 2
11300  1 3
11300  1 3
11300  1 3
11300  1 3
run;
```

The last set of rows with `group=11300` have `x=2` followed by `x=1`.  Your narrative

> within a group

conveys an idea but is not explicitly precise.  The actual grouping (based on the shown want) appears to be a combination of `group` and `x`.  Thus, you will need a

```
by group x notsorted;
```

statement.  The `notsorted` will cause the data step setup the `first.` and `last.` based on continguity of the values instead of the explicit ordering of values.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by group x nostsorted;
  retain z;
  if first.x then do;  * detect first row in combinations "group/x";
    select;
      when (X=1 & Y=1) Z=1;  * apply logic for retained value;
      when (X=2 & Y=1) Z=2;
      when (X=1 & Y=2) Z=3;
      when (X=2 & Y=2) Z=4;
      otherwise Z=.;
    end;
  end;
  logic_tracker_first_x = first.x;
run;

ods listing; options nocenter;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

The output window shows

```
                               logic_tracker_
Obs    Group    X    Y    z      first_x

  1    10600    1    1    1           1
  2    10600    1    2    1           0
  3    10600    1    3    1           0
  4    10800    2    1    2           1
  5    10800    2    3    2           0
  6    10900    1    2    3           1
  7    10900    1    3    3           0
  8    11100    2    2    4           1
  9    11100    2    2    4           0
 10    11100    2    3    4           0
 11    11100    2    2    4           0
 12    11200    2    3    .           1
 13    11300    2    1    2           1
 14    11300    2    2    2           0
 15    11300    1    3    .           1
 16    11300    1    3    .           0
 17    11300    1    3    .           0
 18    11300    1    3    .           0
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried this code but it gives  missing values after the first within each group. Can you attempt it using the have data and see if it works. It may need a bi of tweaking. Thanks!

Comment: See edit, seems to work.  Original was missing semi-colon after `otherwise`, but that should have logged an `ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following:...`  Perhaps you got the error and did not look at the log and was looking at the data output from a prior submit.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. I think the group x notsorted is what was needed as well. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

please try using the following solution , I have used simpler approach by keeping only First Z variable per Group and then did a left join with same dataset to keep the First z variable across remaining observations for same group-

```
data test;
input group 5. x 1. y 1.;
if x=1 and y=1 then z=1;
else if x=2 and y=1 then z=2;
else if x=1 and y=2 then z=3;
else if x=2 and y=2 then z=4;
datalines;
1060011
1060012
1060013
1080021
1080023
1090012
1090013
1110022
1110022
1110023
1110022
1120023
1130021
1130022 
1130013
1130013
1130013
1130013
;
run;

data test1;
 set test;
 keep group x z;
run;

proc sort data=test1; by group x; run;

data keep_first;
 set test1;
  by group x;
  if first.group or first.x;
run;

proc sql;
create table final
as
select a.group, a.x, a.y, b.z
from test a
left join keep_first b
on a.group=b.group
and a.x=b.x
order by a.group, a.y, a.x;
quit;
```

Comment: There are no x and y in your first step's datalines.

Comment: yes .. there are .. 1060011 "10600 1 1" I didn't mention any spaces , so my informat also read 5., 1., 1.

Comment: Ah, see it now, old eyes. Apologies

Comment: Thanks for you response. How do I maintain (or bring back) other variables in the dataset apart from group, x, y &z?

Comment: Ok thanks for this interesting approach using sql to create a table and ten left join. works. Thank you!

Comment: @Richard, no worries :)